# Contrib modules on ros-opencv 2.4

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have ros indigo installed on my laptop (ubuntu-14.04), I want to run opencv code which require contrib modules. How can I install those modules with ros-indigo opencv 2.4?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267140/contrib-modules-on-ros-opencv-2.4/) by [BotLover](https://answers.ros.org/users/30964/botlover/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the only so-called solution hack is referenced [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/149066/how-do-i-use-opencv-30-in-ros-python/) : modify where python looks for modules.

Also related but without actual solution: [this post](http://answers.ros.org/question/219757/how-to-use-opencv-contrib-modules-in-ros-indigo/) and [that one](http://answers.ros.org/question/229246/how-to-build-opencv-extra-module-while-opencv-is-installed-with-ros/).

Hope it's useful to you !

---

Originally posted by [Blupon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27530/blupon/) with karma: 127 on 2017-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BotLover](https://answers.ros.org/users/30964/botlover/) on 2017-07-24**:
I tried the way these links talks about but nothing worked. The problem might be due to the fact that i am running ros & ubuntu on ARM processor.

**Comment by [Blupon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27530/blupon/) on 2017-07-25**:
do you have logs/error messages indicating such a thing ?